# editing a object after solidify

Tags: modifiers

How to edit my object after I use solidify modifier without getting two (doubble) marked vertex at the same time? I need to fix them separated, not together. Anyone?
Im new in the Blenderworld so probably basic stuff but Im stuck with this and it annoys me a lot, need this input for sure. :) Working in 2.8

Comment: Apply the modifier.

Comment: Yes I did and it worked, thanks! Great!

Answer (score 2):

Constructive modifiers (like solidify) only create new verts after applying. So you have to apply them to edit the new geometry.

Form the [blender Manual:]
(https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/introduction.html)

> **Apply**
>
> Makes the modifier “real” – converts the object’s geometry to match the applied modifier, and deletes the modifier.